# How to provide and handle deep links in cordova / phonegap applications

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, cordova-plugins

**Hi 
I would like to know of a Cordova / Phonegap plugin or way to expose and handle deep-links in my Sencha Touch / Cordova App**

So far I am able to deep-link into other applications lets say open Google Play to a specific app detail page.

Using this plugin https://github.com/code4jhon/org.apache.cordova.startapp

So what I would like to do is enable other applications to open specific views or functionalities in my application. I would like to support Android and IOS.

**So bottom line is there a Cordova plugin to expose Activities for Android and their counterparts on IOS ?**

Or how to achieve this?

Looked into Cordova docs but didn't find anything... any help, doc link would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin

It worked perfectly for me.

remember to clean/build after installation

You can handle variable implementing handleOpenURL

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
  console.log("received url: " + url);
}
```

Comment: I've tried defining the function in an independent file an alert the url without success ... hummm

Comment: opening targeted app from another phonegap plugin https://github.com/code4jhon/org.apache.cordova.startapp would prevent  handleOpenUrl to fire ?

Comment: You can define handleOpenUrl function in your index.html before cordova.js reference in a separate script tag. You have several alternatives, it's just a matter of js.

Comment: I haven't used startapp plugin but if you start the targeted app with correct scheme, your handleOpenUrl should be called as expected I suppose.

Comment: oops I by mistake awarded the bounty to the other question, this solution works.

Comment: remember to clean/build after installation

You can handle variable implementing handleOpenURL

    function handleOpenURL(url) {
      console.log("received url: " + url);
    }

Comment: @mentat In which place are you defining the handleOpenURL()? For me it gets called only if I define it in index.html. From index.html i cant change the  state of the app since i dont get the scope of the app.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this using Branch Metrics. They are a new startup and super fantastic.

Check out their cordova plugin docs for deep links here:

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-PhoneGap-Cordova-SDK#initialize-sdk-and-register-deep-link-routing-function

I recommend reading all their docs to get a feel of what to do. However, with Ionicframework and AngularJS, I built a service you could use in your application:

https://gist.github.com/sean-hill/627fa40f96577baae378

After building your project with Branch's plugin, follow these steps for iOS and Android configuration.

### iOS

Add this to your `.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>yourappname</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then `cordova build ios; cordova emulate ios`. To check if it is working, open your emulator, go to Safari and type in `yourappname://` and see if it redirects to your app.

### Android

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file after building android:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="yourappname" android:host="open" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Add this to your `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

Then build again and you should be on your way to great deep linking success!

As per @Deminetix request, this is how I close the Branch session.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    var branch = window.Branch;
    branch.closeSession();  
}, false);
```

Have fun coding :)

Comment: +1 on the cordova config.xml preference. You don't use any of the lifecycle events eg Branch.closeSession()... how come?

Comment: Also, what happens when you click a link while the android app is in the background? It wont see it because it has already been initialised?

Comment: Hey @Deminetix, I do have life cycle events, as I just updated the answer with. Branch Metrics has some magic behind the scenes when a user clicks a Branch link on their phone that will deep link into the App in the background and the run your code.

Answer (score 5):

There's a new plugin that handles Universal Links for both Android and iOS: https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Comment: The plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can use cordova plugins for this. Whole cordova & plugins are meant to establish & execute communication between webpage & native code within the application.

In your case you are trying to allow other apps to have deep links within your app. This could be only done by intent-filter in android & custom-app-url in ios.

[appurl.org](http://appurl.org/) has some pretty nice step-by-step tutorial on handling custom urls. Have a look at following links

- http://appurl.org/docs/android
- http://appurl.org/docs/ios

Comment: thanks @ChitranshuAsthana that was helpful but once in Android Activity or Objective C method how to open the Sencha Touch view ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223642/how-to-open-a-sencha-touch-view-from-an-android-activity-or-objective-c-method can't figure out that gap yet ...

Comment: Your activity which is launched has to be derived from CordovaActivity. You can get wenView and call loadURL. Since you mentioned you are using sencha, I would recommend you to look into Routing mechanism in sencha. The routing will help you in launching diff Sencha controllers on event.

Comment: Thanks @ChitranshuAsthana, makes sense and yes I was looking at routes. Although this approach would still let me with ios to solve ... I'll give it a try to mentat recommendation https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin and come back

Comment: hehehhe I intended to award the bounty to mentat

Comment: Oops.. Is undo possible?

Comment: not that I can see, you did helped me also anyway :)