# How to open a Sencha Touch View from an Android Activity or Objective C method

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cordova, sencha-touch

**How to open a Sencha Touch view from an Android Activity?**

I can define this Activity in the android manifest so when user attempts to open **myawesomeapp://doSomethingSpecificToThisDeepLink** I can do something, i guess I have to provide a class `com.myCompany.AwesomeHandler` ... but from there how can I open a Sencha Touch View ?

```
<activity xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:name="com.myCompany.AwesomeHandler"
          android:label="OpenMyTrustfulApp">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myawesomeapp://doSomethingSpecificToThisDeepLink" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any ideas, examples, doc ref, different approaches would be appreciated. 
At the end of the day what I try to accomplish is to allow other apps to deep link my cordova / sencha touch app (android / ios)

I am trying to do as http://appurl.org/ says in:

http://appurl.org/docs/android

http://appurl.org/docs/ios

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072373/how-to-provide-and-handle-deep-links-in-cordova-phonegap-applications DEEP LINKS