# Deep linking on Windows Phone with phone gap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, intel-xdk, deep-linking

I know it is possible to do deep linking for ios and Android with [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072373/how-to-provide-and-handle-deep-links-in-cordova-phonegap-applications) plugins. However i need to do it also on windows phone, is it possible?

I am developing with Intel XDK over cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Intel XDK doesn't support building Windows Phone apps with Apache* Cordova plugins. There aren't any Cordova plugins for Windows Phone that allow for launching other apps from your application.

Comment: Could you provide a reference about the lack of support of Apache Cordova plugins for WP on Intel XDK? i can't find any evidence against or in suport of it

Comment: Within the current version (1826) of Intel XDK, the only options for Apache* Cordova plugins supported Build targets are [Crosswalk for Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-crosswalk-for-android-build-option?language=it), Android, iOS, and Windows 8. You can only build WIndows Phone 8 Apps that don't support Cordova plugins which can be found under the Legacy section.