# how to redirect to phonegap application if installed, otherwise to Play store

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, deep-linking, custom-url

I have developed an app using phonegap and now i am providing a link to the user, when user click on it, It should redirect to app if installed other wise to Playstore to download the app.
Am using phonegap build.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/365

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, the link you provided will only open the google play app with the app, even if it's installed. An url that opens the app if installed or google play if it isn't installed required a lot of more work, part on the server and part on the app. I'm not going to answer because it's been answered thousand times, just google it

Comment: I'm not answering it either. You are right, this has been answered multiple times before. I did google it. That's why I posted the "stackexchange" answer. I not sure this person knows the differnce.

Comment: Deep link routing is addressed in this answer with the [branch.io](https://branch.io) sdk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072373/how-to-provide-and-handle-deep-links-in-cordova-phonegap-applications/29930638#29930638